# Spring MVC HashMap Form Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, freemarker

I have a hash map in model object. How to bind the hash map when form submission.

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> employeeMap= new HashMap< String, List<Employee>>(); 
List<Employee> employeeList;
//getters and setters of employeeMap and employeeList
```

the Employee Object is

```
class Employee{

String name;
String pincode;
String organization;

//getters and setter

}
```

the form input value is

```
List{ //list iteration here

<input type="text" name="employeeMap[${emp.id}].employeeList[list_index].name" value=""/>
}
```

but it didn't work. please help me how to give the proper input name for binding with the hash map

Comment: Could you please post a more sensible code example. I can't make heads or tails of this...

Comment: I am using freemarker to render the ui side.

Comment: Then you should have tagged it with `freemarker` instead of `jsp`. Fixed it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you have two mistakes:

1. Your map has key as String but your `${emp.id}` is probably int or long,  try use quotes.
2. In map you have list of employees, this list can't have a name, you can just remove it.

Try like this:

```
<input type="text" name="employeeMap["${emp.id}"][list_index].name" value=""/>
```

Here is my similar working example:

```
    User u1 = new User();
    u1.setEmailAddress("email1");
    User u2 = new User();
    u2.setEmailAddress("email2");

    u1List.add(u1);
    u1List.add(u2);
    u2List.add(u2);
    u2List.add(u1);

    userMap.put("1", u1List);
    userMap.put("2", u2List);

    model.addAttribute("userMap", userMap);
```

JSP:

```
Email of second user from map with key=1 = ${employeeMap["1"][1].emailAddress}
```

Comment: I tryed but getting exception like Invalid property 'employeeMap[1][1]' of bean class

Comment: Thank you.. GOT SOLUTION!!!. I TRYED LIKE THIS <input type="text" name="employeeMap["${emp.id}"][list_index].name" value=""/>

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple JSTL `foreach` tag.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:forEach items="${employeeMap}" var="entry">
    <input type="text" name="${entry.key}" value="${entry.value}" />
</c:forEach>
```

By `${entry.value}` you can access the bean properties.

Comment: I need to input something in the input text field that value should bind with the map.. the key should be the value which i am setting suppose the string "key" (<input type="text" name="employeeMap["key"].employeeList[0].name" value=""/>)and the value is the input value that should set in List<Employee> in Map<String, List<Employee>> employeeMap= new HashMap< String, List<Employee>>();